# reference to a variable inside a class

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Basically I want a constant -- **not a `const` reference** --
reference to a variable inside a class.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
    double& a = x;
    double& b = y;
    double& c = z;
}
```

If I set `x = 3` I want `a` to be `3` too
so I want a to be a reference to x
it would be easy with a pointer like `double* a = &x;`
but I don't want to dereference it everytime..

If I compile this I get this message:

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

but thats not the main problem:
if I try now to use them (`a, b, c`) like here:

```
Foo foo;
foo.x = 1.0;
foo.y = 0.5;
foo.z = 5.1;
printf("a: <%f> b: <%f> c: <%f>\n", foo.a, foo.b, foo.c);
```

I get this compiler message:

```
foo.h:5 error: non-static reference member 'double& Foo::a', can't use default assignment operator
foo.h:6 error: non-static reference member 'double& Foo::b', can't use default assignment operator
foo.h:7 error: non-static reference member 'double& Foo::c', can't use default assignment operator
```

foo.h:5 is `double& a = x;`
foo.h:6 is `double& b = y;`
foo.h:7 is `double& c = z;`

so **what** is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize references through assignments. They need to be initialized in the constructor's initializer list, like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
    double& a;
    double& b;
    double& c;
    Foo() : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}
    // You need an assignment operator and a copy constructor, too
    Foo(const Foo& rhs) : a(x), b(y), c(z), x(rhs.x), y(rhs.y), z(rhs.z) {}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) { 
        x=rhs.x;
        y=rhs.y;
        z=rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: hmm now i get `error: non-static reference member 'double& Foo::a', can't use default assignment operator`

Comment: @Schnizel1337 It ran perfectly for me ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/kkpdyF)).

Comment: yea, i saw, but try to set `foo` to another instance of `Foo`, then you get the errors: see http://ideone.com/5qJisq

Comment: @Schnizel1337: Yeah, that's the way to do it but why on earth would one want that?

Comment: @Schnizel1337 That's because you did not add an assignment operator ([link](http://ideone.com/wP3Xw4)).

Comment: @BalogPal ok let me explain: in my project `Foo` is a class named `Vector3`
now i want to abuse the vector class for a `Color3` :) -- so i want to have the member variables called `r g b` and not `x y z` -- clear?

Comment: @Schnizel1337: And you're aware that it means 3 extra pointers to carry and say goodbye to assignability, right? The usual path is to make yor r,g,b functions, the extra () on clients are light enough, and prevent all runtinme costs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you! I missed the operator -- I'm such an idiot :) -- thank you veeeery much, it's now working! -- maybe you could add the operator to your answer? would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is really that you are trying to assign a reference in the definition of the type. That's not going to work, since `a` and `x` will have different locations depending on where the `Foo` object is placed.

You need to do that after the `Foo` object has been created, which means in the constructor

Foo() : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}

Note that it would ALSO be invalid to try to initialize the reference after the construction - it HAS to be done in the constructor and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The default assignment operator can't be used because you have reference members. It has nothing to do with how you initialize them or what you initialize them to. It is due to the fact that references cannot be "re-seated".

It would be helpful if you post the line that causes the problem. You must have something like `foo1=foo2;`. Your solution is to write your own assignment operator.